# Reference request on the non-injectivity of space-filling curves

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

- Suppose $C$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$ with nonempty interior and $C$ is equal to the closure of its interior, and $f:[0,1] \twoheadrightarrow C$ is continuous and surjective. Then $f$ is not one-to-one. (If I'm not mistaken, a corollary is that the set of points in $C$ whose inverse-image contains more than one point is dense in $C.$)
- Suppose replace the assumption that $C$ has nonempty interior and is equal to the closure of its interior to the assumption that $C$ has positive measure, and the image of every subinterval with positive $1$-dimensional measure has positive $2$-dimensional measure. I suspect we can get the same conclusion.

My question is: Where are the best published proofs of these propositions?

Secondarily, will any such proofs fit neatly into an answer posted here? (If so, maybe that could also be "accepted".)

Comment: If $f$ were bijective, then would it not be a homeomorphism? *A continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homemorphism*. No measure theory needed there.

Comment: I suspect no generality is lost by making the following the hypothesis of the second proposition: The $1$-dimensional measure of each subset of $[0,1]$ equals the $2$-dimensional measure of its image.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen : So you may be reducing the problem to that of showing that certain spaces are not homeomorphic to each other.

Comment: Yes. And then we are back to the simple old: *A line segment minus a point is not connected, a plane region minus a point is.* Not saying anything about the interesting measure-theoretic questions in here. Just a simple proof for the first part.